# MIPS BMI calculator print issue

Tags: mips

```
.data
wpr:.asciiz "Weight (whole pounds): "
hpr:.asciiz "Height (whole inches): "
bpr:.asciiz "\nCalculated BMI: "

weight: .word
height: .word
bmi:    .float

.text
main:
    li $v0 33
    li $a0 52
    li $a1 20
    li $a2 22
    li $a3 127
    syscall
    
    # Prompt weight
    la $a0 wpr
    li $v0 4
    syscall
    
    # Load input into saved register $s0
    li $v0 5
    syscall
    move $s0 $v0
    
    # Prompt height
    la $a0 hpr
    li $v0 4
    syscall
    
    # Load input into saved register $s1
    li $v0 5
    syscall
    move $s1 $v0
    
    # Calculations
    mul $s0 $s0 703
    mul $s1 $s1 $s1
    
    mtc1 $s0 $f20
    cvt.s.w $f20 $f20
    mtc1 $s1 $f21
    cvt.s.w $f21 $f21
    div.s $f12 $f20 $f21
    
    # Output BMI
    li $v0 4
    syscall
    la $a0 bpr
    syscall
    li $v0 2
    syscall
```

When I run this code Everything works fine but I get the height prompt printing twice. I dont know what the issue is. Heres an example of the output

Weight (whole pounds): 150

Height (whole inches): 71

Height (whole inches):

Calculated BMI: 20.918468

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your last block of code (with "# Output BMI") to

```
# Output BMI
la $a0 bpr
li $v0 4
syscall
li $v0 2
syscall
```

Currently you tell the system to output to the prompt first, which still contains your previous height prompt.